# Regarding multi-module project, can I set each port?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

In a multi-module project, can normal users use the public port and the admin can set it to use the localHost port?

I know each port can use a different port, but I want to know if I can mix public and localhost ports.

I'm still a beginner, so I've set up 2 localhost ports in a hands-on project, not a real server. in actual use
I wonder if it is possible to operate with one localhost and one actual port instead of two localhosts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on your question so apologies in advance if this is not helpful.

In a normal [monolithic module application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_application) (which is what I think you're talking about) there's only one main class (and method) so only the one port required.
Any changes to the port number in any other modules will be overridden by whatever is set in the main 'driver' module's settings.

For example if you have `server.port=8081` in your main driver module's `application.properties` file, but then another module called `admin` that defines `server.port=8082` in it's properties file, `8082` will get overriden with `8081`.

The normal approach would be to define domains (using endpoints) that separate the zones, and then [allow users access to each zone based on their roles using Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration).
For example:

- Users with the role `ROLE_ADMIN` might be able to access anything including `your-host/admin/**`
- Users with the role `ROLE_USER` might only be given access to `your-host/public/**`

If you're specifically looking for a solution with different port numbers, I suggest using a microservices architecture rather than the modular monolith approach, where each service is it's own application and runs independent of each other.

If you search [modular monolith vs microservices](https://www.google.com/search?q=modular+monolith+vs+microservices&sxsrf=ALiCzsZOV7rdGfcPPA8MdvFjEa8-6O9zGg%3A1666760145605&source=hp&ei=0b1YY9GSIsPw4-EPkc-yoAg&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAY1jL4YIOj3YE9osTGQi3-4Dpak12zjkW&oq=monolith+modules+vs+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzoHCCMQ6gIQJzoECCMQJzoFCAAQkQI6CAguENQCEJECOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QM6CAgAELEDEIMBOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQrwE6BQgAEIAEOggIABCABBCxAzoOCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQ1AI6CAgAEIAEEMkDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARCvAToFCC4QgAQ6BwgAEIAEEAM6CwguEIAEEMcBENEDOg0IABCABBCxAxBGEPkBOggIABAWEB4QD1CmCVjyUWCWY2gBcAB4AIAB1wGIAfcbkgEGMC4xNy4zmAEAoAEBsAEK&sclient=gws-wiz) you will find lots of interesting reads

Comment: thank you! Thank you very much for providing detailed information.